# Working with tabular cumulative data

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am kind of lost how to achieve this, while I would not even need to think how would I do it in the code behind.

Imagine that there is some data in a grid, and that there is first column which is start time. Then I have a column called duration.

The entity itself has StartTime and EndTime properties, which are saved to database. I added Duration, which is a computed property.

There are 3 rows in a grid:

```
StartTime   Duration (min)
12:40       105
14:25       186
17:31        72
```

If a user changes 14:25 to 14:35, this means that EndTime for 1st row and StartTime for 2nd row is changed. This also mean that duration for both 1st and 2nd row should be computed and updated.

So, how can I do this in MVVM architecture, when user changes StartTime in a grid, that everything is updated?

With code behind I could do this in 10 minutes. :)

Comment: Sometimes MVVM breaks and should be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia describes a ViewModel like this:

> The view model is a 'model of the view' meaning it is an abstraction of the view that also serves in mediating between the view and the model which is the target of the view data bindings.

Therefore, your ViewModel should have the properties `StartTime` and `Duration`, whereas your Model should have the properties `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

According to MVVM's way of thinking, it is the ViewModel that performs the necessary calculations to transform the StartTime/Duration value pair to StartTime/EndTime.

Comment: So, how would I "transform the StartTime/Duration value pair to StartTime/EndTime"? How would I pair Grid StartTime column,  to a VM StartTime property? And how would I notify VM that a particular value in StartTime column has been changed? Normally in MVVM architecture you bind grid to collection property of a VM, which is actually the representation of model (data).

Comment: @Goran: the ViewModel's purpose is to represent the view; the ViewModel does not represent the model. You typically connect the data grid and the ViewModel via data binding, i.e. you have one ViewModel for the list of rows (e.g. `IList<RowViewModel>`) and one ViewModel for a single row (here: `RowViewModel`) which as the `StartTime` and `Duration` properties. The transformations between StartTime/Duration to StartTime/EndTime takes places in the ViewModel (with C# or VB code, of course). How you connect the ViewModel and the model depends on how your model is designed.

Comment: Can you point me to any example that documents what you are saying? I have read couple of MVVM books and there is no such example that you are describing, so its difficult for me to understand just by reading a short explanation.

Comment: And to explain what I meant with "...bind grid to collection property of a VM, which is actually the representation of model (data)". The property of VM itself represents model (data) - example ObservableCollection<Person>, so View is binding to model (data) through VM.

Comment: A good introduction is this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx; the accompanying code (see AllCustomersViewModel.cs) shows that you should use `ObservableCollection<XxxViewModel>` in the ViewModel, i.e. you should normally never expose model data directly to the view. I.e. in your case, you would use `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` instead of `ObservableCollection<Person>`.

Comment: I have read the article, and saw that Josh is duplicating all properties, so they are available in ViewModel. Since this is not the way my application is currently build, and I am exposing model data directly to view through ViewModel, I am going to need to find some workaround.